# How do I iterate through a file in Ruby while using "peek" and not lose half of my data?

Tags: ruby

I need to iterate over each line in a file. However, after I read in one line, I need to look ahead at the next line and possibly take some action.

If I use the `peek` command then I only ever get the second line of the file. However, if I use the `next` command to move the iterator, it increments the `.each` iterator as well. To see what I mean run the 9 line program below and look at the output. If you comment line 7 out then the entire file will print, but the `peek` will be wrong. If you leave line 7 uncommented, then the peek works but you only get half the file printed.

I either need a way of only incrementing it once, or I need a way of iterating over a file without using `.each`.

What is the best way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby                       
                                   #1  
curFile = File.open("testcase.rb")     #2  
line_enum = curFile.to_enum            #3  
curFile.each do |line|                 #4  
  puts "=> " + line                    #5  
  puts "  peek > " + line_enum.peek    #6  
  line_enum.next                       #7  
end                                    #8
```

Comment: The super obvious solution, knowning nothing else about your program, is to simply stop using `peek`, and retain the line read in the previous iteration and treat it like the "current" value and treat the currently read value as the "peek"'d value.

Answer (score 1):

IO and File include enumerable, so the `each_cons`method is available:

```
cur_file = File.open("test.csv") do |f| #using a block takes care of closing the file
  f.each_cons(2) do |line1, line2|
    puts "=> #{line1}"
    puts "peek #{line2}" 
  end
end
```

Output:

```
=> one
peek two
=> two
peek three
=> three
peek four
```

Comment: Definitely a good idea, but in this way `line1` never reaches the last line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `each_with_index`

```
curFile = File.readlines("testcase.rb")       

curFile.each_with_index do |line, index|                  
  puts "=> " + line                    
  puts "  peek > " + curFile[index+1]    if index < curFile.count

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `peek`ing through the file, why not first read all the lines in with:

```
 lines = File.readlines('testcase.rb')
```

That will give you an Array of all the lines. Then you have more flexibility about how to iterate over them. This would probably suit your needs:

```
 (lines + [nil]).each_cons(2).each do |line1,line2|
   # do something
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about turning the problem around? Instead of thinking of it as peeking forward why not look back?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby                        #1  
curFile = File.open("testcase.rb")     #2  

prev_line = nil
curFile.each do |line|                 #4  
  if prev_line
    # do something to prev_line based on the content of line  
  end

  prev_line = line # turn the current line into prev_line for the next iteration
end                                    #8
```

Comment: I might have to so something like that though initially I did not because I wanted to possibly print the first line depending on what was on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop instead of `#each` and move the cursor manually:

```
curFile = File.open("peek.txt")
line_enum = curFile.to_enum
while line_enum
  line = line_enum.next
  puts "=> " + line
  puts "  peek > " + line_enum.peek
end
```

**EDIT**

Depending on what you want to achieve exactly you can also use `#loop` instead of a `while` loop. In this case it will break out of the loop when `line_enum.peek` is called at the end of the file:

```
loop do
  line = line_enum.next
  puts "=> " + line
  puts "  peek > " + line_enum.peek
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As an outline for what you're trying to do, I'd use something like:

```
previous_line = nil
File.foreach("testcase.rb") do |li|

  if previous_line

    # Do tests based on "previous_line".
    # If you need to know the current line use "li". 

  end

  previous_line = li
end

# do something to test the "previous_line" by itself 
# if it's possible to have something important there.
```